# Updating the picklist values in VisualForce/apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, picklist, dependent-picklist

Is it possible to have two control fields for a picklist field?Can we achieve it by Visualforce?

I have three fields.Sold (Checkbox), Onsite (Picklist) and FlagStatus(Picklist).

If Sold field is checked, FlagStatus should display only two values(Mandatory,Optional).
If any value from Onsite is selected, then it should display another two values(Decline,Accept).

Please help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use onchange javascript (javascript function control the picklist values) on **Sold** and **FlagStatus** to control(add/remove) the value of **Onsite** pick-list on runtime. (Just a thought you need to identify what happens to  **Onsite** pick-list when both **Sold** and **FlagStatus** are selected).

Thanks
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create multiple picklist for FlagStatus and render a particular picklist according to the values selected in other controls.

Following example would be helpful for you,

[reRender commandButton depending on selectOption value in visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32816/rerender-commandbutton-depending-on-selectoption-value-in-visualforce)